# filter quickfix buffer vim

Tags: vim, grep, buffer

I want to filter results in my quickfix buffer , after reading some answers on SO I tried setting the buffer to modifiable , but the problem is if I delete a line and enter on the same line to jump to that file , It still takes me to the previous result (which has been deleted).

Example 

        `1 file1`

        `2 file 2`

lets say I delete file 1 from quickfix window now

        `1 file2 (press enter)`

It takes me to file 1 instead of file 2 .

Comment: Answers can be of a better quality when you tell us what you intend to achieve, not just ask about a technical detail out of context. You probably can achieve the desired result using functions `getqflist()` and `setqflist()`, but if you are only intending to find or remove an specific pattern from the quickfix it may be easier to use `:g/<pattern>/#` or `:v/<pattern>/#`.

Comment: So one of my most common use case is that I grep something and then I want to refine the results with some `:g/<pattern>/#` command , it does change the buffer , but when I press enter to jump to the line numbers , it still takes me to the previous result file . So I think the problem is that vim maps the jumps with line numbers and not the actual content. So maybe if there is some way to say something like buffupdate or something which can update the quickfix buffer to have correct jump mappings

Comment: Command `:g/<pattern>/#` doesn't changes anything on buffer, it only print the lines that matches the pattern along with the line number. Thus there is no way it would change how the jump is performed on quickfix window.

Comment: Oh i am sorry i meant `:g/<pattern>/d`

Comment: So, if you use with `#` instead of `d`, you can see the desired line number on quickfix and jump to it with `:<line number>`. If you need to do this more than a few times then you can change the content of the quickfix window --  fo the "buffupdate" you said, you could use `getqflist()` to retrieve the contents of the windows, filter it, and the use `setqflist()` to replace the contents, then it should behave properly. But if your use case is grep, then you should consider using a better pattern on your grep in first place, then you wouldn't have the need of editing the quickfix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `getqflist()` to retrieve the contents of the quickfix window, filter it, and the use `setqflist()` to replace the contents, then it should behave properly.

There are some plugins that you could check:

- [QFixToggle : Toggle the visibility of the quickfix window](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1375) - changing the visibility would be equivalent to deleting, and make it easier to correct if you delete too much.
- [editqf : Make quickfix entries editable](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3557)

Comment: I marked this as the answer because I found a plugin which basically behind the scenes calls these methods to get the quickfix enteries and perform some command on them , it's called Peeja/vim-cdo, It provides the Cdo (quicfixdo)and Ldo(locationdo) . Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

does this little script help?

[QFGrep](https://github.com/sk1418/QFGrep)

it can

- filter(Grep) entries in Quickfix
- restore original Quickfix entries

Comment: I've searched vim.org, but somehow I missed your plugin. I've just tested and it works very well.

Comment: @mMontu here it is: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4490 but better use the github version, it is always the latest.

Comment: Indeed, when I posted the message above I've already tested it from git.